# Order of the side bar items

Tags: seedstack

Is there a way to reorder entries of the side bar of a w20-business-theme based web application having its master page generated automatically (other than using categories).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort side bar's entries, we need to use the sortKey property.

Small example:

```
    "routes": {
  "home": {
    "template": "<h1>Hello World!</h1>",
    "hidden": true
  },
  "components1": {
    "templateUrl": "{demo}/views/components.html",
    "sortKey": 10
  },
  "components2": {
    "templateUrl": "{demo}/views/components.html",
    "sortKey": 30
  },
  "components3": {
    "templateUrl": "{demo}/views/components.html",
    "sortKey": 20
  },
  "components4": {
    "templateUrl": "{demo}/views/components.html",
    "sortKey": 50
  }
}
```